# Start Visual Studio 2019 instance from terminal

Tags: visual-studio, terminal

Quick question: is there a way to open a Visual Studio 2019 instance from terminal?

I know you can open a VS Code instance by doing something like this `code .`.
But is there a way to do this for VS 2019 (and VS 2022)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the command is `devenv.exe`. It is normally in the path. If you provide a solution or project file as argument, it starts up with that one open. Note that there's also (for historical reasons, I think) a file called `devenv.com` which takes precedence and is launched if you only type `devenv`. This usually works, but may, from my experience, fail when used with some arguments.